# Unknown command: 'syncdb' Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, banco-de-dados, python, visual-studio-2013, django

Estou tendo dificuldade em desenvolver um sistema em Django.
Quando tento sincronizar o banco aparece esse erro:

```
Python interactive window. Type $help for a list of commands.
Executing manage.py syncdb
Unknown command: 'syncdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
The Python REPL process has exited
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está utilizando o django 1.9, o syncdb foi removido, veja o release:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9

Para rodar as migrações, você deve usar o makemigrations e migrate.

Criou ou alterou tabela:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
#Irá criar arquivos de migrações com as coisas que você fez
```

Executar migrações:

```
python manage.py migrate
#Irá aplicar as alterações no banco.
```

Comment: Correto. Estou usando django 1.9! Não sabia deste "detalhe"

Comment: Devo usar este comando no visual studio ??

Comment: Bom cara, particularmente eu não gosto de windows. Mas a raiz do  problema era isso. A partir do django 1.7, os camandos para fazer e executar as migrações são esses dois. Existia o syncdb até a 1.8
Você tentou executar esses comandos? Deu algum problema?

Comment: executei sim...

Comment: I found your solution but **I don't know where should I type the commands, please guide me:**
python manage. py makemigrations # will create migration files with the things you've done
Run migration:
python manage. py migrate

Answer (score 0):

Alex, o Dias está correto. 
O comando syncdb foi descontinuado.
Em seu lugar utilizo os 2 comandos abaixo e exatamente nesta sequência, para não ter problemas com o BD do Django Admin:

`python manage.py migrate auth
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Comment: Utilize o campo `comentar` quando não estiver respondendo.